# After hovering the cursor over the image - arrows must appear on the left and on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have auto-moving images as a slideshow.

Here's my code in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Krzysiek_39/pen/poNLbgx

I would like the left and right arrows to appear only after hovering the cursor over the image (as "cursor: default"). When the default cursor is behind the image, the two arrows are to be invisible.

Here's a perfect example of how this is supposed to look like:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Infinite-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-LoopSlider/

Do you know how to do it?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

```
<div class="header">

    <div class="text">
        <a class="refresh" title="A website refresh">Website</a>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="menu-container">

    <div class="menu">
        <a>MENU</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="slider_wrapper">
    
        <div class="slider">
        
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?art" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 1</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?action" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 2</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?war" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 3</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?crime" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 4</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?drama" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 5</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?sci-fi" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 6</span></a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="slider_objects">
        
            <div class="slider_btn prev_btn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
            <div class="slider_btn next_btn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
            
            <ul class="slider_list_wrapper">
                <li class="slider_list active_slide"></li>
                <li class="slider_list"></li>
                <li class="slider_list"></li>
                <li class="slider_list"></li>
                <li class="slider_list"></li>
                <li class="slider_list"></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:hover` on `slider` class.

```
.slider_btn {
   opacity: 0;
}

.slider:hover + .slider_objects .slider_btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```